# How to improve Columnstore Index Scan

Tags: sql-server, performance-testing, query-performance, columnstore

Can any one tell which DB server properties will affect the Column Store Index batch execution ?

Answer (score 1):

The question, as asked, is way to broad. There are many 'DB Server' properties that affect batch execution. An obvious one to look at is the [database compatibility level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx), witch documents effect on batch execution:

> In level **120**:
>
> - Sorts on a table with Columnstore index are in Row mode
> - Windowing function aggregates operate in row mode such as LAG or LEAD
> - Queries on Columnstore tables with Multiple distinct clauses operated
>     in Row mode
> - Queries running under MAXDOP 1 or with a serial plan executed in Row
>     mode
>
> In level **130**
>
> - Sorts on a table with a Columnstore index are now in batch mode
> - Windowing aggregates now operate in batch mode such as LAG or LEAD
> - Queries on Columnstore tables with Multiple distinct clauses operate
>     in Batch mode
> - Queries running under Maxdop1 or with a serial plan execute in Batch
>     Mode

This is just the tip of the iceberg. Another example of 'DB server property' is [traceflag 4199](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/974006), which affects many query optimizer fixes and some are batch mode related. Available server memory affects batch mode. Available number of CPUs affect batch mode. Data size and cardinality estimations affect batch mode.

So, really, you have to narrow down the question to something specific.

As for the title question, 'how to improve columnstore scan', the biggest bang for the buck is segment elimination. Read [Understanding Segment Elimination](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5651.understanding-segment-elimination.aspx).

But, first and foremost, understand how to troubleshoot performance issues. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/). Root cause your problem. Is possible that you need more RAM, not a different index. Measure.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using SQL 2014 server. What about the "max degree of parallelism" and "cost threshold for parallelism"